# Split or individually edit repeating Google Calendar events

Tags: google-calendar

Our company just moved from Microsoft Exchange with Outlook to Google Mail, Calendar, etc. and I am trying to modify a calendar event where it repeats, but the times across the days are not the same.

I created an event from 10h00 to 16h30 and made it repeat for two days. Now the times need to be adjusted independently for the two days. I could just cancel the repeat and book a new appointment for the second day but the event has a confirmed room booking and with rooms at a premium I worry that someone else may grab the room before I can create the new second day event.

Outlook had a way to modify repeating events individually but I'm not seeing anything like that in the Google Calendar web client. So my question is whether there is a way to individually edit repeating events, or failing that, to split the repeating event into individual ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on the instance of the event you want to modify and edit it. You'll be prompted to change just that instance, future instances, or all instances.

[image: Modify one instance of repeating event]

Comment: That works perfectly. Not too discoverable, happening only after you make changes you think will affect all repeating events, but great once you know of the behaviour.

Comment: this doesn't work perfectly if you then want to move the event that was changed to a different calendar